Forbid temporary lifetime extension in C++
Assume a deleted constructor is added to std::string_view as following:
// Cannot construct a string_view from a temporary string
string_view(string const &&) = delete;

With this change, the following code would fail at compile time:
// You can't do this anymore
std::string_view sv = std::string{"A"} + std::string{"B"};

However this wouldn't:
// Oops
std::string_view sv = (std::string const &)(std::string{"A"} + std::string{"B"});

What can be done in string to forbid the result of the concatenation to be converted into a string const & (which doesn't extend the lifetime of the result, and thus the string_view is dangling).

There's nothing you can do.

Thanks @HolyBlackCat . Was hoping there could be something, but oh well.

I guess you could ban constructing it from rvalues, but then it won't work properly for function parameters.

@HolyBlackCat I thought about it and I'm better off leaving things as-is. Thanks for your help!

C++ is designed to protect against Murphy, not Machiavelli.  But even then, C++ gives you enough rope to shoot yourself in the foot.

Checking: your desire is that something would prevent the following (valid) line? std::string const & s = std::string{"A"} + std::string{"B"} That is, block the reasonable in order to prevent your somewhat pathological example?

@JaMiT Not necessarily, I'd be happy if both my example fails and your example works. Looking at it further I can see that there's always some "reasonably-working" code that will be broken, but I might be wrong...

@Eljay Sure, I understand that. If someone would write the last snippet, they are definitely shooting themselves in the foot, be it compile time error or a segfault/whatever. I'm just trying to see how far I can get :).
